# Select Distinct Sql Server Question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure.

```
 A | B | C
```

I wish to pull column A and B where all the results of A and B are distinct. I wish to ignor column C. My unerstading of the distinct keyword that it looks at the whole row not jst the columns you return. Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: it's better to give example data & output expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so. DISTINCT looks at whatever columns you specify. So for you, `SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM table`.

I'd prefer the GROUP BY though: `SELECT A, B FROM table GROUP BY A, B`

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is wrong. DISTINCT does not look at the whole row. Did you try something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A, B) FROM t WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT doesn't look at the whole row in the database, it just looks at the requested columns. So you can just do SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM mytable and it will completely ignore column c.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct a,b,row_number()over (partition by a order by a) as rn into #T1 from
(select distinct b,a from table)d

update #T1
set a =null where rn > 1

select a,b from #T1